# Spark: How the collectByValue of a list type RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The type of RDD is list.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([[1,3], [3,4]])
```

I want to count each scalar value, such as `1,3,4`.

I expected a dict like: `{1:1, 3:2, 4:1}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten it first with `flatMap`, then `countByValue`:

```
rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).countByValue()
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1})
```